# Run Selenium Python script on Android with Pydroid Selendroid

Tags: python, android, selenium, selendroid, pydroid

I have to run this Selenium Python script on Android.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument('--log-level=1')

s=Service("C:/Users/Python/chromedriver")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=chrome_options)
driver.get('https://www.amazon.it/dp/B08T769JQD')


title = driver.find_element(By.ID, "productTitle").text
print(title)
```

I tried Pydroid, but when i use "pip install selenium", i have this error.

[image]

I have the last pip version installed.

I tried to install Rust with "curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://sh.rustup.rs | sh", but i have this error.

[image]

I saw that exists [Selendroid](http://selendroid.io/), but how can i implement it with my script and Pydroid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

/storage/emulated/0 pip install --no-deps selenium

this will ignore other installation

working in Pydroid

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).